# What is the Windows phone control used in

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit

On windows phone 8/8.1, in settings->ringtones+sounds what control us used for the ringtones and reminders options. The control displays a list of items on a dedicated page with a header "chose an item"

Comment: I need this for my app development. Can't find the control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `<ListPicker>` from the Windows Phone Toolkit  (You can get it my using NuGet)

[The Windows Phone Toolkit Website](https://phone.codeplex.com/)

---

Sample Usage (notice the separate templates for fullscreen mode)

```XAML
<toolkit:ListPicker>

    <!-- normal template -->
    <toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                        
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>

    <!-- full screen template -->
    <toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                        
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:ListPicker.FullModeItemTemplate>
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```